# DataGridView behaves oddly when in a UserControl in a TabPage

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabcontrol

I have a Textbox and a DataGridView in the two panels of a SplitContainer, which is in a Panel in a UserControl in a TabPage in a Winform.

The TabPages (and thus the UserControls) are created dynamically.

- Data loads into it correctly.
- When I bind more data than can fit on the grid, it displays scrollbars as expected.
- I can't click anywhere in the grid. Can't select data. Can't scroll. Can't even see the scrollbar position indicator blocks.
- The textbox in Panel1 works fine.
- The DataGridView, SplitContainer Panel, and SplitContainer are not readonly and are enabled.
- SelectionMode is set to CellSelect.

I have tried:

- Setting Dock to None and Anchor to all four sides of the splitcontainer panel
- Setting Dock to fill
- Docking the SplitContainer in a Panel created for this purpose. I saw something on the Googles about how they resize.
- Moving the DataGridView outside of the SplitContainer and Panel
- Removing the Panel (which was just in here for troubleshooting this issue anyway)

I haven't tried moving the DataGridView out of the userControl, because then it's just another grid on a winform, which would eliminate part of its purpose.

I have found that the SplitContainerPanel's Click event fires when I click it, but the DataGridView's does not. So the problem must be somewhere between the two.

It's basically a very simplified SSMS.  Assume I can't just use that.

[image: example of the problem]

Comment: I created such control structure without any problem. It's better to post a simple code to reproduce the problem.